# 1 Router, Several HTTP Proxies

Tags: router

Is there a way to have a single router with many devices using different HTTP proxies? For example, a single router with 10 devices connected needs to have each device connected to a different proxy. The proxies cannot be set on the machine itself if you're curious as to why I wouldn't just set proxies at the machine. I am not familiar with routers so please speak in laymens terms.

**note by barlop**

Corrected his question to state HTTP proxies, which is what he meant, rather than just proxy, which was somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Do you mean HTTP proxies or what? // And still correct way is to set up each device. Better research how to do this instead of searching for dubious solutions of unexpected complexity.

Comment: Yes HTTP Proxies

Comment: Routers really don't have anything to do with HTTP proxies since HTTP is an application-layer protocol, not a network-layer protocol.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, and it sounds like a really bad design choice as well.

Proxies manage the connection to a service from a device (usually web service), but if they are not set up on the device itself so the device knows where to go, then the device will just attempt a standard connection and your proxy has to catch the attempted connection from the device in transit.  This is usually known as a transparent proxy.

All those intercepts still need to be caught in the same place however, the router, and with the same rule to match the connection type.  You can't bind multiple proxy services to the same service rule, no hardware would know which one you intended to run.  You don't have a router for each device, you just have one router, so you just have one proxy service.

You should probably re-examine whatever problem you are trying to address and see if there's another way to look at it or rephrase it.  Researching routers and proxies in general may help as well.  Depending on your situation, it may be possible to configure a single proxy to apply different policies for different client devices, I am not familiar enough with such services to say how to do so however.

Comment: I could do per-device rules, for example, using --mac-source. So each device COULD have its own rule which will redirect requests to its own proxy. This is not going to make the idea much better, however.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - Yes, but for someone who's not familiar with routers...? You can do anything with enough iptables but I'm presuming he just has ten devices and a router, and unless it's a generic box acting as a router instead of a vendor router, I'm not sure you can even set up one transparent proxy right on the box, let alone ten of the exact same service running.

Answer (score 0):

The first point I want to make: never ask people "help me to do something strange, but only speak my language". You always have to learn their language before asking. So you have no other options, only make yourself more familiar with all this router stuff, or pay someone who is already familiar and could do the work for you.

So you need a router with ability to redirect packets to proxies; most, if not all, SOHO routers can't do this. More, you should be able to enter arbitrary firewall rules, not just a single checkbox "do transparent proxying". This could be a conventional PC running some Linux distro, or some Cisco router, or something like this. Any router which is able to do your task will have a command line interface and the CLI will be primary and recommended, or even the only way to configure it.

You will need to run these proxies somewhere. For example, this could be the same conventional PC running 10 independent instances of some proxy software (this is not very easy task to run 10 independent proxies in one system), or 10 virtual machines (or OS containers) with proxies, which could be much easier but will require more resources. I often use Squid for proxying, it could do transparent proxying and I will prefer LXC containers, but I'm not sure if LXC environment will suffice, it needs investigation.

Decide how you will identify your devices. This could be an IP address, or MAC address if there are no other routers between your one and these devices.

When you've done all decisions, you could return here and ask how to configure the stuff you have chosen.